# Как получить в список определенные строки treeview в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

Всем добрый день! Коллеги нужен ваш совет! Пишу программу для фильтрации данных на tkinter. Возник вопрос с `treeview`. (я его пытался описать ранее но видимо не правильно сформулировал...)
у нас есть таблица со строками `treeview`.
В эту таблицу мы вносим значения:

```
def Update():
    text = Serial_text.get()
    parametr = choice_parametr.get()
    tree_4.set(tree_4.selection()[0], 1, parametr)
    tree_4.set(tree_4.selection()[0], 2, text)
```

После чего я хочу получить эти данные:

```
for k in tree_4.get_children():
    test = tree_4.item(k)["values"]
    new_list = []
    new_list.append(test)
    filter_1 = [t for t in new_list if len(t) == 3]
    print(filter_1)
```

На выходе я получаю следующее:

```
[['job_id', '=', 4564]]
[]
[]
[['status', '!=', 'qwerty']]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

- программа в переменную  `filter_1` загоняет все строки из treeview в том числе пустые и все они формата list.
  В связи с чем у меня два вопроса как удалить пустые элементы (пробовал все в том числе и `null`) и привести данные к одному списку. Большое спасибо!!!

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, вы хотите вот такую реализацию:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ws = Tk()

tv = ttk.Treeview(ws, columns=(1, 2, 3), show='headings', height=8)
tv.pack()

tv.heading(1, text="f")
tv.heading(2, text="g")
tv.heading(3, text="h")


tv.insert(parent='', index=0, values=("rg", "dsgd", 100.00))
tv.insert(parent='', index=1, values=("anl", "e2", 10.00))
tv.insert(parent='', index=2, values=("ank", "3", 40.00))
tv.insert(parent='', index=3, values=())
tv.insert(parent='', index=4, values=("ti", "4", 20.00))

data = []
for k in tv.get_children():
    test = tv.item(k)["values"]
    if type(test) is list and len(test) == 3:
        data.append(test)
print(data)

ws.mainloop()
```

Вывод:

```
[['rg', 'dsgd', '100.0'], ['anl', 'e2', '10.0'], ['ank', 3, '40.0'], ['ti', 4, '20.0']]
```

Comment: gord1402 3 дня... 3 дня я делал то же самое но ничего не получалось, а почему спросите вы да потому что в принт я выводил в цикл из  за чего у меня выводилось все! Огромное спасибище!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!